# Iphone flip views using block animation methods

Tags: iphone, animation, methods, block, transition

Hi
I have looked without success for the answer to this.
Am trying to flip views on iphone app. Rather than using the usual iOS3 methods I want to use block methods to animate the transition.
Can anyone suggest a snippet of code to help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                 animations:^{
                                 // Exchange the views here
                                 [view1 removeFromSuperview];
                                 [mySuperview addSubview:view2]; 
                             }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: UIView's `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion` might also work well in the above example (swap out the views rather than use subviews). Just remember to set `self.view = newController.view` in the completion block.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work, my view are swapped immediately without flip

Comment: Syntax error: extra ";" after the "animations" block declaration.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the animateWithDuration method suggested above, and it didn't work. I couldn't get it working until I used the following:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:viewOld 
                    toView:viewNew
                  duration:.75 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
                {
                    // cleanup viewOld
                }
 ];
```